# How can I retrieve raw body buffer from loopback custom method to verify stripe signature from webhook POST?

Tags: node.js, express, loopback

Following the guide at: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-official-libraries

I've tried this code within a loopback custom method:

```
    "use strict";
module.exports = function(Webhook) {
  Webhook.stripe = function(req, data, cb) {
    const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    const endpointSecret = "whsec_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];

    let event;

    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(data, sig, endpointSecret);
      Webhook.create({
        data: data
      }); 
      console.log("Success");
      cb(null, "OK");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      Webhook.create({
        data: err 
      }); 
      cb(err);
    }   
  };  

  Webhook.remoteMethod("stripe", {
    accepts: [
      { arg: "req", type: "object", http: { source: "req" } },
      { arg: "data", type: "object", http: { source: "body" } } 

    ],  
    returns: [{ arg: "response", type: "any", root: true }]
  }); 
};
```

But when verifying the signature in `stripe.webhooks.constructEvent`, passing in the data object of the body won't work because it doesn't want an object, it wants the raw un-edited body. (JSON.Stringify() doesn't work either, since this alters the body and the verification fails) How can I get the raw unedited body from loopback to pass into stripe library for signature verification?

Comment: Have you tried `source: "payload"`?

Comment: Tried that, no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Felipe Figueroa from https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/loopbackjs/I2LK5gOkP_4/rn73-B0ABwAJ for this answer.

body-parser will parse incoming requests according to the body parser type (in this case, json or raw) according to the content-type. You can't set both raw and json parsers to apply sequentially

To solve this issue we can remove bodyParser.json from middleware and configure it manually in server.js

Since we need the raw body but also need the converted JSON, we can add an additional property to request object before the JSON parser activates like this:

in middleware.json:

```
"parse": {
    "body-parser#json": {"params": {"limit": "10mb", "strict": false}}, // remove this line
    "body-parser#urlencoded": {
      "params": {
        "extended": true,
        "limit": "5mb"
      }
    }
```

in server.js:

```
function rawBodySaver(req, res, buf, encoding) {
  if (buf && buf.length) {
    req.rawBody = buf.toString(encoding || 'utf8'); // additional property set on req object
  }
}

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '10mb', strict: false, verify: rawBodySaver}));
```

then in the code above we'd use:

```
event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req["rawBody"], sig, endpointSecret);
```

and then the signature verifies correctly.